# Can custom code be used in ssrs to populate a parameter that allows multiple values?

Tags: reporting-services, custom-code

The title pretty much sums it up.  I have a parameter that can handle multiple values and I want to know if I can use custom code to populate the parameter with multiple values.

More info: What I have is a parameter that represents an academic year, in the form YYYY-YYYY.  What I want to do is have some custom code take that year, determine the semesters in that year and return them all as another parameter.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Your question is somewhat broad, and the only answer to it is "yes" - if you can give more detail about the implementation you're aiming for, you'll probably get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on the web and it worked for me:

```
public function setParameter ( ) as string()

dim str(0 to 2) as string
str(0)="value1"
str(1)="value2"
str(2)="value3"

return str
End function
```